# Woocommerce Attributes Pulling data in alpahabetic order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My Problem is trying to pull the size attributes for the different products. So, for that i used this php code

```
<?php 
        $terms = get_terms('pa_size');
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo "<li>" .$term->name. "</li>";
         }
 ?>
```

The size attributes displaying for the above code should be in alphabetic order such as like L, M , S , XS instead of XS, S, L, M, XL, XXL. Help me out from these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [asort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)

```
$terms = get_terms('pa_size');
asort($terms);
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo "<li>" .$term->name. "</li>";
}
```

For Testing purpose.

```
$terms = array("XS","S","L","M","XL","XXL");
echo '<pre>';print_r($terms);echo '</pre>';
asort($terms);
echo '<pre>';print_r(($terms));echo '</pre>';
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a846ef96268879a2e0baae3c69177ef028f00ed7)

**array before sort**

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => XS
    [1] => S
    [2] => L
    [3] => M
    [4] => XL
    [5] => XXL
)
</pre>
```

**array after sort**

```
<pre>Array
(
    [2] => L
    [3] => M
    [1] => S
    [4] => XL
    [0] => XS
    [5] => XXL
)
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Terms are ordered alphabetically by default however WooCommerce applies a filter which changes the ordering.

To change the order back to alphabetical you need to set `menu_order` to false in your arguments for `get_terms()`.

Example:

```
$terms = get_terms( 'pa_size', array(
    'menu_order' => false,
) );
```